# Laravel access model's property in relation method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a relation method for a model which has a condition based on a property of the model itself.

```php
// ProductController.php

    public function show($id, Request $request) {
      $product = Product::find($id);

      if ($request->exists('optionValues') {
         $product->load('optionValues');
      }
    }




// Product.php

    public function optionValues()
    {

/// here $this->stock_status_id is null. actually all attributes array is empty.

        if ($this->stock_status_id == Stock::CUSTOM_ORDER) {
            return $this->hasMany(ProductOptionValue::class, 'product_id', 'product_id')
                ->where('status', 1);
        }

        return $this->hasMany(ProductOptionValue::class, 'product_id', 'product_id')
            ->where('price', '>', 0)
            ->where('quantity', '>', '0')
            ->where('status', 1);

    }
```

but it seems when Laravel is loading a relation all properties are null. 
and `$this->stock_status_id` for current model is null, and I can't check for the condition.

Is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: How do you get your model, you call option values on? Laravel does not set values to null when loading relationships.

Comment: @mrhn in controller after getting the product via `$product = Product::find($request->id)`, I call `$product->load('optionValues')`

Comment: You should go with [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes) for this case.

Comment: @Tpojka a little bit more clarification if it's possible?

Comment: Have you checked purpose of scopes in documentation? There you would find how to pass arbitrary (in this case `request('optionValues')`) parameter.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 hours of debugging I discovered that Laravel has different way of loading relations when using `$model->load('relationName')` method than calling it via `$model->relationName`

When using `->load('relationName')` method the instance of model has no attributes yet even when all attributes have been loaded properly before calling `$model->load()`.

But when using `$model->relationName` on a model instance, the instance have all the attributes present when trying to load the relation.

So, I changed this line of code

`$product->load('optionValues');`

to this:

`$product->optionValues;`

And the condition checking in the `optionValues()` method, works as expected.